# how to a regex for similar string

Tags: ruby, regex

i have this string

```
[url=test.php]test[/url]
```

or

```
[url=http://test.php]text[/url]
```

I want to a regex get this

```
[url=http://test.php]text[/url]
```

example:

before:

```
str = "[url=test.php]text[/url]"
str.gsub(/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/,'[url=http://\1]\2[/url]')
=> "[url=http://test.php]text[/url]"
```

question:

```
str = "[url=http://test.php]text[/url]"
str.gsub(/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/,'[url=http://\1]\2[/url]')
=> "[url=http://http://test.php]text[/url]"
```

so..  two "http://"

Any ideas anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question.

You need a regex that only matches `[url]` BBCode tags if the linked URL is *not* starting with `http`.

```
\[url=\s*(?!http)([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[/url\]
```

should work:

```
str.gsub(/\[url=\s*(?!http)([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/,'[url=http://\1]\2[/url]')
```

Explanation:

```
\[url=\s*   # match [url= literally, plus optional space
(?!http)    # assert that it's not possible to match http here
([^\]]+)    # match 1 or more characters except ], capture in \1
\]          # match ]
(.*?)       # match link text, capture in \2
\[/url\]    # match [/url]
```